# Global Menu Bar wont refresh?

Tags: unity, globalmenu

While the question itself may sound vague, basically what is happening is when I minimize an application (firefox for example) all the options as well as the option to minimize maximize or close stay in the global menu bar until I click onto the actual Desktop. Is this an error thats always been around that I havent noticed or is it new popping up in 14.04?[image: As you can see, Firefox is clearly minimized, but all of the options are still open in the global menu,and even appears as its still opened in the sidebar]

Comment: What is your graphic card?

Comment: Intel Sandybridge Mobile onboard Graphics

Comment: **Update** Turns out Unity was seeing Conky as an open window, and basically wasn't allowing the Desktop to render as the open "window"